# How to access linked docker container's host with react

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

My application has three containers: db, frontend-web(React), backend-api
How can I get my backend-api address in frontend-web

Here is my compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://api:8080/
    links:
      - api
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    build: ./api
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I can't get the address both api and process.env.API_URL

Comment: Give your api container a name and that name will automatically be resolvable in your web docker. So if you name it "myapp-api" then http://myapp-api will be reachable in web container.

Answer (score 0):

Add the container name to the service description as follows:

```
api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

You can then use the container name as a host name to connect to. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/containername

Answer (score 0):

I am admitting that your server at the `web` container is just providing the static htmls and not working as a proxy for the `api` container server.

So, once that you mapped the ports to the host machine, you could use the host machines name/ip to find the api server.

If your host machine name is `app.myserver.dev`, in your `API_URL` env var you can use the config below and docker will do the work for you:

```
  web:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://app.myserver.dev:8080/
    links:
      - api
    depends_on:
      - api
```